# Division of screen using div tag

Tags: html, css

I have a main div of width 757 pixels and height 484 pixels. I want to divide this div into 3X3 squares.
I have no idea how to do this using HTML5 and CSS3?

Comment: You could create 81 child divs and set the width:calc(100% / 9) height:calc(100% / 9)

Comment: ....and float them all left. *Don't forget to contain the floats!*

Comment: are you trying to get a grid that has 9 squares to a side? Or divide the space into a bunch of squares that are each 9px by 9px?

Comment: I am so sorry. I need 3 x 3 not 9 x 9. I mean total 9 squares.

Comment: @nivea you do not want 9x9 squares trust me lol, you want your page to be divided in a 9 by 9 grid, there is a BIG difference lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal boxes CSS.

```
.box {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: calc(100% / 3);
    background: #bada55;
    float: left;
    outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  width: 757px;
  height: 484px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.box {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  background: #bada55;
  float: left;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: @Paulie_D but this doesn't answer his question! Ha-Ha

Comment: Actually it really does....and s/he said so   :)

Comment: @Paulie_D I agree, you solved their issue, it was just funny to me that literally what they asked for was something completely different.

Comment: @Paulie_D My answer was built for the literal sarcasm

Comment: SO isn't about sarcasm.

Answer (score 0):

I added color to show you more visually where the boxes are.

HTML:

```
<div class="Main">
    <div class="Main-Top">
        <div class="Main-100" id="color1">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="Main-010" id="color2">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="Main-001" id="color1">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Main-Middle">
        <div class="Main-100" id="color2">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="Main-010" id="color1">
            5
        </div>
        <div class="Main-001" id="color2">
            6
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Main-TBottom">
        <div class="Main-100" id="color1">
            7
        </div>
        <div class="Main-010" id="color2">
            8
        </div>
        <div class="Main-001" id="color1">
            9
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Main {
    width: 757px;
    height: 484px; }
.Main-Top, .Main-Middle, .Main-Bottom {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; }
.Main-100, .Main-010, .Main-001 {
    float: left;
    width: calc(757px/3);
    height: 161px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; }
#color1 {
    background: #b8fccb; }
#color2 {
    background: #ff0000; }
```

Added JSFiddle so you can tinker it a little if you want

http://jsfiddle.net/xo3yax9j/1/

Answer (score -1):

LOL!!! here ya go, exactly what you asked for!!! http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/hhftbyqk/5/

```
.container{width: 757px; height: 484px; overflow: hidden;}
#one{width: 9px; height: 9px; float: left; background-color: blue;}
#two{width: 9px; height: 9px; float: left; background-color: red;}
#three{width: 9px; height: 9px; float: left; background-color: lightblue;}
#four{width: 9px; height: 9px; float: left; background-color: green;}
#five{width: 9px; height: 9px; float: left; background-color: lightgreen;}
```